# lightweight asyncio web server

Tags: python, http, python-asyncio

As far as I can tell, [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org) is currently the reference for web servers built on [asyncio](http://asyncio.org). While it's an impressive piece of work, it doesn't quite match my particular (peculiar) taste: In addition to being a web server, it's also a framework for web applications (with routing and everything), plus the API is fairly class-heavy.

I'd prefer something that is *just* an HTTP server, providing a minimal interface (basically an async WSGI equivalent). Does such a thing exist already?

Comment: [asyncio.org](http://asyncio.org), which you actually linked to in your question, turns up [aiowsgi](https://aiowsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which seems like it might fit the bill.

Comment: I had seen that, but it's kind of hard to assess whether it's more than an experiment: There's not much activity on the GitHub repo - which isn't necessarily a bad thing, but some peer review would certainly help.

Comment: Just be aware that putting blocking WSGI on top of an async web server can be problematic. If the WSGI request runs in the same thread as the async loop, it blocks the async loop. You basically have a WSGi server that can handle only one request at a time. For a single host/post, you would be better off looking at 'waitress' if want WSGI interface but some of the underlying benefits on an async web server.

Comment: As far as I can tell, aiowsgi is actually based on waitress (which uses threads I believe) - thus my earlier concern about it possibly just being an experiment: It doesn't seem like a "pure" asyncio approach, but rather layering asyncio on top of a different paradigm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you may try low-level `aiohttp.server` instead of `aiohttp.web`.

It has no routes, middlewares and other high-level stuff.
But you have to work with `aiohttp` low-level abstractions like *message*, *payload* and *response*.

Comment: Thanks - given that there don't seem to be any alternatives (yet?), this is probably my best option.